# Trills in Clementi Op. 36 No. 1 2nd movement

Tags: piano, trills

This is related to this discussion: [How to play these trills from Clementi's Sonatina in C Major on piano?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/38319/how-to-play-these-trills-from-clementis-sonatina-in-c-major-on-piano)

[image]
My question: is the **FG** at the end of AGAG**FG** part of the trill, or is it the one explicitly shown in the original score (blue circle) right after the trill note G? The image I'm attaching seems to have discrepancy. In Measure 3, that **FG** (orange cicle) seems to be the one in the original score (blue circle), which is consistent with Neil Meyer's first image in the previous discussion linked above. However, in Measure 25, there is no **FG** in the original score following the trill note G, but the trill is suggested to be played as before, AGAG**FG** (red circle). If the **FG** belonged to the trill of the G note, then one would play FG twice in Meausure 3: AGAG**FG FG**.

Could someone please clarify? (My Willard Palmer edition shows the same as the above from sheetmusic2print)

Comment: I'll let others answer at more length, but I hope they'll include and explain the word _nachschlag_.

Comment: Although Clementi printed the "FG" in the [first edition](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/f/fd/IMSLP801193-PMLP6617-clementi_g.132.-4.-_Six_Progressive_Sonatinas_for_the_Piano-Forte_Op.36.pdf), it doesn't have to be significant that it's omitted in the next-to-last measure; he might expected it to be understood.

Comment: So which way is more stardard/common? When I see a similar trill elsewhere in future, should i always play that FG part in case it's not printed? or it depends on the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ornament is played the same way in both cases — the FG occurs only once in each — it just happens to be scored differently.

The FG are a *nachschlag*, which is

> the auxiliary closing note or notes usually played at the end of a trill
> ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nachschlag))