# What is the best way to notate/convey this ornament?

Tags: piano, notation, composition, musescore, ornaments

I'm currently writing a piece of music (solo piano) which has a certain ornament. This is the way that I want it to be played: [image: The ornament that I need to notate]

It would be really nice if I could notate it something like the following: [image: How I want it to look.] or [image: Also a possibility for how it should look.]

However, I'm not sure how I should notate it. I was trying some different things on MuseScore, and I found that the following (in the automatic playback) sounds perfect: [image: Sounds correct on MuseScore]. However, after doing some research on mordents and ornament types, this doesn't seem right, and that particular symbol looks like it should be a trill (with upper prefix), not 'mordent with upper prefix' as MuseScore calls it. EDIT: After further listening, it is *just* discernible that it is a full trill (with 4 notes) rather than just a mordent. At the speed of the playback I was using it was almost indiscernible.

Could anyone help me with which ornament type I should use in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ornament you're looking for is called a *nachschlag*. (See, for example, [Trills in Clementi Op. 36 No. 1 2nd movement](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/124352/70803).)

Presuming treble clef, the notation you want will look like an eighth-note B, two 32nd-note grace notes leading to a sixteenth-note A, and then the sixteenth-note G#.

[image: Nachschlag example]

The other ornament signs, such as the trill and mordent, are presumed to take their time-value away from the beginning of the note being ornamented.

To do this is MuseScore, use the "Grace: 32nd after" button on the Grace Notes menu.

[image: MuseScore Grace Notes menu]

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much. I may end up using 64th notes (if possible), this is what I was looking for.